# Find all comments matching a query on different youtbue videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I know it is possible to [list comments](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments) for a single video on youtbue but is it possible to find all comments on youtbue data api v3 that match a query?

For example if I search for "BMW" I find all comments on different videos with "BMW" in it. If it is not supported what would be a work around?

I am using python.

Comment: what does the documentation say?

Comment: I won't ask here if I find the documentation helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Comments: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list#request) 
>  Returns a list of comments that match the API
>   request parameters.

There is a filter parameter which will return the only certain comment ids,  (why you would want to do this no idea)

> id string
>  The id parameter specifies a comma-separated list of
>   comment IDs for the resources that are being retrieved. In a comment
>   resource, the id property specifies the comment's ID.

For the Google methods that do allow you to do a string search (Which is what I think you are looking for) the parameter is normally q.

[search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) has this option you can search for videos by text string, Google drive file.list also has it you can search for files that start with a name or type.

Answer:  by checking the documentation we can see that it is not possible to find all comments on YouTube Data API v3 that match a string query.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I also don't understand the idea behind giving comment ids to comment:list. Regarding to search.list I am able to search for videos with their descriptions but I need the comments. Since youtbue search tool does not support search for comments I guess using a crawler also cannot help to find comments with a phrase. What do you think about a crawler solution?

Comment: crawler sounds like a hack to me.

Comment: It is a hack but I am not even sure that hack could work at all